# Symfony 3, установить id = 0

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine2

Здравствуйте! ПОдскажите, пожалуйста, как в Symfony 3, установить id  чтобв он начинался с нуля.

Сейчас в Entity классе написано так:

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="id", initialValue=0)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
```

и id начинается с 1, а нужно с 0.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Что происходит?**

Аннотация `@ORM\SequenceGenerator` имеет эффект только при использовании вместе с:

```
/**
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
 */
```

Вы же используете:

```
/**
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
```

что делает аннотацию `@ORM\SequenceGenerator` бесполезной.

Сразу хочу отметить, что MySQL не поддерживает последовательностей, а значит вы не сможете использовать `strategy="SEQUENCE"` с этой базой данных.

**Что делать?**

1. Правильнее всего было отказаться от идеи начинать идентификаторы с нуля. Строго говоря, `id = 0` лишен смысла (как, впрочем, и `id = -1`).
2. Если очень хочется, вы можете задать начальное значение `auto_increment` в ручную:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE something AUTO_INCREMENT = 0;
   ```

   Чтобы это работало, вам так же придется задать режим [`NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero).

Comment: спасибо, вы помогли разобраться!